# Racket Emacs mode for mimicking Scribble or HTDP sample code examples?

Tags: emacs, racket, htdp

I really like the syntax highlighting and coloring of the code samples throughout How to Design Programs.  For example:

http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_6.5

Does anyone have something like this as a jumping off point for an Emacs major mode for editing source code?

Comment: Do you just mean the color scheme, or is there some sort of functionality that you want?

Answer (score 4):

Neil Van Dyke created an [Emacs major mode](http://www.neilvandyke.org/scribble-emacs/) for editing Scribble documents.  It doesn't color the source code, unfortunately.  But it's the best way to edit documents with embedded Racket code in Emacs.

In the realm of non-Emacs editors, DrRacket does highlight both code and text correctly in Scribble documents.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're looking for a Emacs major mode with source highlighting support?  If you are, take a look at http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html, which describes several of the Emacs major modes that support Racket and come with source highlighting.